# How plesk uses AWS for their storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, plesk

Currently exploring the relation between `Plesk` and `AWS`

As of now my AWS account showing the Memory Disk `SSD Usage` of `30GB` of my account

Where it says 40%+ of memory are being used out of `30GB`

[image]

and Relational Database System of AWS showing no current data

[image]

and my AWS Account doesn't run a single instance of `ec2`

My question is, how does the `Plesk` uses `AWS` when it comes to storage?

Because as of now My plesk contains  the files of my wordpress site and database of site using phpmyadmin (`mysql`)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you’ve got a 12GB EBS volume created for your EC2, you’re charged for that even if your EC2 is stopped.

Go to *EC2 -> Volumes* and check it out. It may be in a different region than you’re looking at.

Comment: Hello, response appreciated. What's the best way to stop for now billing?

Comment: @RaeIan you are not being billed. You can have up to 30GB EBS volume in the free tier.

Comment: Just in case, in a few months and it overlaps to 30gb free tier and higher. Is there a possibility to affect my site by getting slow access and crashing?

Comment: @RaeIan EBS volumes don’t grow on their own, you would have to extend it or create a new one to run over the limit. In which case you’d know. If you keep just this 12GB volume you’re safely within the free tier. Besides EBS price is pretty small - just a couple cents per GB-month. Note however that the free tier is free only for the first 12 months, after that AWS will start to charge your credit card.